# How to show extra content with a slug?

Tags: wordpress

This is a single.php and for example url is
http://url.com/sample-post/

I added some extra content with Advanced Custom Fields plugin and show it in the content. Everything is all right here but I want to show this extra content like http://url.com/sample-post/extra-content/

Is it possible? If yes how can I make it? I've been searching for hours but I have not found anything.

I hope you understand me and so sorry for my bad english. Thank you everyone who will help.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<main class="content" role="main">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php the_field('some-extra-content'); ?> // Extra Content
<?php endwhile; ?>
</main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

please try below code for ACF

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<main class="content" role="main">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php echo get_field('some-extra-content', $post->ID); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same url but you could use a query string.

http://url.com/sample-post?extra=true

```
<?php
if($_GET['extra'] === 'true'){
    the_field('some-extra-content');
}
?>
```